# Typescript error when using React useContext and useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, react-hooks

I'm new to Typescript and I'm getting the following error on my variable `state` in using `useContext` and `useReducer` hooks:

> Type '{ state: {}; dispatch: Dispatch; }' is not assignable to
>   type '{ latlng: null; searchTerm: null; bookingId: null; myPin: null;
>   selectedPin: null; selectedCard: null; selectedCardPin: null; }'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'state' does not
>   exist in type '{ latlng: null; searchTerm: null; bookingId: null;
>   myPin: null; selectedPin: null; selectedCard: null; selectedCardPin:
>   null; }'.ts(2322)

This is my `app.tsx`:

```
const App = () => {   
  const initialState = useContext(Context)   
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState)    
  return(
    <Context.Provider value={{ state // <-this is where the error occurs//, dispatch }}>
         ...
    </Context.Provider>    
  )
```

Following is my `context.jsx`:

```
const Context = createContext({
    latlng: null,
    searchTerm: null,
    bookingId: null,
    myPin: null,
    selectedPin: null,
    selectedCard: null, 
    selectedCardPin: null,
})
```

Revision:

according to the advise, I've changed my `context.tsx' to the following, but still getting the error message:

> Argument of type '{ latlng: null; searchTerm: null; bookingId: null;
>   myPin: null; selectedPin: null; selectedCard: null; selectedCardPin:
>   null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MyContextType'.
>   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'latlng' does
>   not exist in type 'MyContextType'.ts(2345)

```
import { createContext } from 'react'

interface MyContextType {
    dispatch: React.Dispatch<any>,
    state: {
      latlng?: any,
      searchTerm?: any,
      bookingId?: any,
      myPin?: any,
      selectedPin?: any,
      selectedCard?: any, 
      selectedCardPin?: any,
    }
}

const Context = createContext<MyContextType>({
    latlng: null,
    searchTerm: null,
    bookingId: null,
    myPin: null,
    selectedPin: null,
    selectedCard: null, 
    selectedCardPin: null,
})

export default Context
```

2nd revision:

When I change my `context.jsx` to match the contents of `createContext` as following:

```
interface MyContextType {
    latlng?: any,
    searchTerm?: any,
    bookingId?: any,
    myPin?: any,
    selectedPin?: any,
    selectedCard?: any, 
    selectedCardPin?: any,
}

const Context = createContext<MyContextType>({
    latlng: null,
    searchTerm: null,
    bookingId: null,
    myPin: null,
    selectedPin: null,
    selectedCard: null,
    selectedCardPin: null,
})
```

the error is gone in `context.jsx`, but it causes a type error in app.jsx.

> Type '{ state: {}; dispatch: Dispatch; }' is not assignable to
>   type 'MyContextType'.   Object literal may only specify known
>   properties, and 'state' does not exist in type
>   'MyContextType'.ts(2322)

```
    <Context.Provider value={{ state //<-- here //, dispatch }}>
    </Context.Provider>
```

Comment: Declare a type with optional properties like `interface MyContextType = { dispatch: Function, state: { latlng?: string, ... } }` then use `createContext<MyContextType>({ ... })`

Comment: @p.s.w.g I made the change as you mentioned, but am still getting the error

Comment: Sorry, for not being more explicit. You'll have to provide the `dispatch` and wrap `state` as well to match exactly what you expect to use in`<Context.Provider value={}`, e.g. `createContext<MyContextType>({ dispatch: null, state: { latlng: null, ... }})`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g It seems that if I match the interface to the states in `context.jsx`, it solves the type error within `context.jsx`, but it causes an error in `app.jsx` where state from value doesn't recognize `MyContextType`

Comment: Maybe you need `interface MyContextType = { dispatch: Dispatch<any>, state: any }`? That would sacrifice significant type safety, but it seems like your state object is very loosely defined anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 'as type' when you pass prop to `Store.Provider`, it can fix this error. Like this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
const value = { state, dispatch };
return <Store.Provider value={value as MyContextType}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>;
```

Let me know if this solves your issue.